# What's wrong with the code although i have defined the function already?

Tags: python, python-3.6

this code gives NameError showing i havenot defined the function but i actually defined the function in a class.

I tried alot but couldnot resolve it.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def printList(self):
        temp = self.head
        while temp:
            print(temp.data)
            temp = temp.next

    def append(self, new_data):
        new_node = Node(new_data)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node
            return
        last = self.head
        while last.next:
            last = last.next
            last.next = new_node

    def merge(self, head1, head2):
        temp = None
        if head1 is None:
            return head2

        if head2 is None:
            return head1

        if head1.data <= head2.data:
            temp = head1
            temp.next = merge(head1.next, head2)

        else:
            temp = head2
            temp.next = merge(head1, head2.next)

        return temp

list1 = LinkedList()
list1.append(10)
list1.append(20)
list1.append(30)
list1.append(40)
list1.append(50)

list2 = LinkedList()
list2.append(5)
list2.append(15)
list2.append(18)
list2.append(35)
list2.append(60)

list3 = LinkedList()
list3.head = merge(list1.head, list2.head)

print("Merged Linked List is : ")
list3.printList()
```

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-22fca0a2d24d> in <module>()
     57 
     58 list3 = LinkedList()
---> 59 list3.head = merge(list1.head, list2.head)
     60 
     61 print("Merged Linked List is : ")

NameError: name 'merge' is not defined
```

Comment: You need to make a [mcve]. This is way too much code.

Comment: `merge()` is not a function, it's a method that should be called from a `LinkedList` instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined `merge` as a method of the `LinkedList` class. That means you need to call it on an instance of the class, not just by itself. For instance, you could replace the `merge(...)` call causing your current exception with `list3.merge(...)`, and the recursive call inside the method with `self.merge(...)`.

But I'm not really sure it needs to be a method, so you could instead move the function definition out of the class (and remove its `self` parameter). It would work just fine as a stand-alone function.